# CSV File Not uploading data in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, fgetcsv

I can't upload a data in csv starting with letter 'C' and space

```
       C R MOHAN,3102,II,D,,cin45l@yahoo.com,1234567890,
       S R ALEX,3102,II,D,,xuy566@yahoo.com,1234567880,
  CHARMILA,3102,II,D,xu5566@yahoo.com,1234567880,
```

The second  and third line got inserted in db,but whenever a line stating with 'C' and then space is not inserting in db.pls help

Answer (score 0):

use below function by passing the values in it

```
function escape_string($data)
{
    $result =   array();

    if(is_array($data)){
        foreach($data as $row){
            $utf_data =  mb_convert_encoding(str_replace('"', '',trim($row)), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
            $result[]   = str_ireplace('?', '', $utf_data);
        }
    }else{
        //return utf8_encode(str_replace('"', '',trim($data)));
        $utf_data =  mb_convert_encoding(str_replace('"', '',trim($data)), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
        return str_ireplace('?', '', $utf_data);
    }
    return $result;
}
```